# Bash - write to visudo

Tags: linux, bash

I want to write something to visduo and I can't write to /etc/sudoers

```
for SERVER in $(cat some.txt); do

ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$SERVER '

echo 'm2madm ALL=(ALL:ALL)   NOPASSWD:/sbin/iptables -L' | sudo EDITOR='tee -a' visudo

'
```

problem is with '

but I really don't know what I should do, can you help me please?

the output is:

```
domain_check.sh: line 25: syntax error near unexpected token `('
domain_check.sh: line 25: `echo ('m2madm ALL=(ALL:ALL)   NOPASSWD:/sbin/iptables -L' | sudo EDITOR='tee -a' visudo)'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use variables in the string you sent trough ssh, enclose that string with `"`. Within the string you should use a single quote `'`, or escape every double quote `\"`.

Your problem occurs because you "close" the string before you're meaning to. The following should work.

```sh
for SERVER in $(cat some.txt); do
ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$SERVER "
echo 'm2madm ALL=(ALL:ALL)   NOPASSWD:/sbin/iptables -L' | sudo EDITOR='tee -a' visudo
"
done
```

P.s. there is a shell spell check site in which you can test your code. I don't know which, but I will add it as a comment below my answer.

Comment: https://www.shellcheck.net/ is the site you're looking for. I've just checked it out and it's really neat.

Comment: thank you, but now i got sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
but I don't know why, it is impossible to do with this command ?

Comment: ok I got it, changed to: ssh -ttt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@"$SERVER" " thank you so much